# Sending rich text over POST in rails app using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have in APP A the following rich text:

A nice basketball

- because I say so
- because my mother says so
- because my dog says so

In index.html.erb this rich text is accessible through `product.body_html`, which I load into a Javascript object called `myProduct`:

```
var myProduct= new Object(); 
myProduct.desc ='<%= JSON.generate(raw(product.body_html), quirks_mode: true) %>';
```

Then I send this object via POST to my API in APP B using Javascript:

```
var url = appBURL + "/myapi/method";
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify(myProduct),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
        // data.desc should contain the same rich text
        $(".myDiv").html(data.desc);
      }
  });
```

And I get an answer back `data.desc` in app A that *should* contain the same rich text. But when I display `data.desc` inside a `<div>` what I see printed on the screen is this

```
"<p>A nice basketball</p> <ul> <li>because I say so</li> <li>because my mother says so</li> <li>because my dog says so</li> </ul>"
```

And what I'm actually inserting in that `<div>` (i.e., the contents of `data.desc`) is this

```
"&lt;p&gt;A nice basketball&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;because I say so&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;because my mother says so&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;kjh&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;"
```

The client in APP A is adding these quotes. Why?

If I add in APP A the description like this:

```
myProduct.desc ='<%= raw(product.body_html) %>';
```

Then it works with normal text (and it doesn't add the quotes), but as soon as I have rich text it produces a syntax error when running the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are rendering the text in APP B, render like this:

```
(CGI::unescapeHTML data.desc).html_safe
```

Comment: That's right! The problem was that I needed to unescapeHTML in APP B. I used `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(data.desc)` in my Java servlet. Thanks!